# How do I get the index of a column by name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Given a `DataFrame`

```
>>> df
   x  y  z
0  1  a  7
1  2  b  5
2  3  c  7
```

I would like to find the index of the column by name, e.g., `x` -> 0, `z` -> 2, &c.

I can do

```
>>> list(df.columns).index('y')
1
```

but it seems backwards (the `pandas.indexes.base.Index` class should probably be able to do it without circling back to list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
print (df.columns.get_loc('z'))
2
```

Another solution with [`Index.searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html):

```
print (df.columns.searchsorted('z'))
2
```

**Timings**:

```
In [86]: %timeit (df.columns.get_loc('z'))
The slowest run took 13.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.99 µs per loop

In [87]: %timeit (df.columns.searchsorted('z'))
The slowest run took 10.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.48 µs per loop
```